# functon вернуть несколько значений

Tags: php

Исходные данные:

```
$array  = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$param1 = '...';
$param2 = '...'

$value = some_func($param1, $param2, $array);

function some_func($p1, $p2) {
    ...
    unset($array[0]);          // внутри ф-ии кроме прочего, изменяется массив
    $value = 40 + 2;
    ...
    return $value;
}
```

Суть вопроса: как мне в основном теле программы получить измененный внутри функции массив? Перебрал уже много разнообразных костылей, но получается путанно и неочевидно. Иди сама постановка задачи идиотская?

- `list($value, $array) = some_func(...);` мне не нравится эстетически.
- `$value = some_func(..., ..., &$array);` <del>вызывает ошибку `strict standards`</del> (оказывается не вызывает, был напуган)
- загонять все в класс и обращаться из функции к свойству класса `$this->$array` вариант, но хотелось бы процедурного решения

Comment: можно массив спрятать в `function some_array($operation) { static $array = ...; }` но тогда я не смогу работать с массивом как с `массивом`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во-первых, *unlink($array[0]); // внутри ф-ии кроме прочего, изменяется массив* - это удаляется файл :) массив изменяется `unset($array[0]);`

во-вторых, чтобы иметь доступ к массиву, его надо передать в качестве аргумента функции или объявить глобальным. Если второе , то вы его поменяете, и он поменяется :) А если первое, надо сказать в объявлении функции `&$array`, тогда он будет передан по ссылке, и все изменения тоже сохранятся. А вот вызывать такую функцию надо без амперсанда `func($array)`

Comment: разумеется, техническая опечатка, спасибо. ночь на дворе )))

Comment: я еще понаписал

Comment: `global` одно из решений, но некрасивое и опасное. проект уже большой и будет расти, не услежу за всеми глобалами :) а `&$array` было бы красиво, но не работает ни там ни там, потому что `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: здрасьте, приехали. Половина стандартных функций так работает. вот, смотритте, ни одного предупреждения https://eval.in/410573. Посмотрите, где вы что ставите

Comment: пардона просим, действительно работает. это у меня внутри функции уже была ошибка.

Comment: со всеми бывает, особенно к ночи. удачи!